# Javascript replace all '-' with '/'

Tags: javascript, regex

looking for a simple regex to change 2014-08-30 to 2014/08/30. I tried `replace()` but that only works for the first occurrence obviously.

Comment: `strreplace` isn't a JavaScript function.

Comment: `.replace(/-/g,"/");` ?

Answer (score 0):

`'2014-08-30'.replace(/-/g, '/')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var re = /-/g; 
var str = '2014-08-30';
var subst = '/'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `replace()` function in JS

Try this:

```
var str = "---";
str = str.replace(/-/g,'/');
alert(str);
```

Result:

```
///
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xhuyrfje/)**